# Who decides if a question topic is closed as duplicate while it is not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicates

I came across this: [Photos in my SD Card suddenly disappeared and now I cannot recover](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106712/photos-in-my-sd-card-suddenly-disappeared-and-now-i-cannot-recover?noredirect=1#comment240676_106712)

It was closed because assumed a duplicate of [How can I recover deleted photos from an SD Card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-recover-deleted-photos-from-an-sd-card)

I'd argue it is not, it is a completely different issue which I explain in answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1386707/my-folder-turned-into-a-usb-file.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, but quite honestly, it's probably a better fit for Super User SE. And if the Photo SE question was moved to Super User SE, it *would* be a duplicate to the Super User SE question you've linked...

Comment: Thank you, I understand.

Comment: Question is now reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have sufficient reputation, you can vote to reopen a closed question.

Or you can flag the question for moderator's attention and explain why *you think* it should be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways a question may be closed as a duplicate.

- Moderators have the ability to close any question as a duplicate by their own action without requiring any input from anyone else.
- Users who have earned a Gold Badge connected to a tag associated to the question when it was originally posted also have the ability to close a question as a duplicate by their own action without requiring any input from anyone else. High reputation users with gold badges for a particular tag are assumed to have enough expertise in that area to appropriately judge if two questions addressing that subject are enough alike to be considered duplicates.
- If five users vote to close the question for any reason, and the most common reason between those five is that the question is a duplicate, then the question will be closed as a duplicate and any other questions designated in the close votes will be listed as duplicates. That is, if one person votes the question is "opinion based", another votes that it is "off topic", and three others vote it is a duplicate, with two of those voters suggesting it is a duplicate of "Question A" and another voter suggesting it is a duplicate of "Question B", the question will be closed as a duplicate of both Question A and Question B.

There are also several ways for a question to be reopened. **These are usually done after the question has been sufficiently edited to make clearer the differences between the closed question and the suggested duplicate(s).**

- Any user who has enough reputation can vote to reopen a closed question. It takes a total of five users voting to reopen a question for the question to be reopened.
- A moderator may reopen a question without requiring any other action from anyone else.
- If the question was closed by a high reputation user with the Gold badge "hammer", that same high reputation user can reverse the decision and reopen the question. Once reopened, the same user can not close the same question again, or even add a vote to the votes of four other users to close it again.